# PointerLockControls threejs "null is not an object (evaluating 'instructions.addEventListener')"

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, es6-modules

I am trying to integrate PointerLockControls into my project.
I am using the example from the THREEJS examples page and I've basically copied the exact thing over and it still gives me errors in console and won't run. Im using a basic code structure and am importing three via node module and express server.

this is my main html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>-</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css"> -->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .blocker {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }

        .instructions {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-box;
            display: box;

            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
            -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
            box-orient: horizontal;

            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -moz-box-pack: center;
            box-pack: center;

            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
            box-align: center;

            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 24px;

            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="blocker">

        <div class="instructions">
            <span style="font-size:36px">Click to play</span>
            <br /><br />
            Move: WASD<br/>
            Jump: SPACE<br/>
            Look: MOUSE
        </div>

    </div>


    <script type="module" src="client.js">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my client.js file:

```
//---------- Imports

import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';
//import {OrbitControls} from '/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {PointerLockControls} from '/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls.js';
import Stats from '/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';






//---------- Setup

let camera, scene, renderer, controls;

const objects = [];

let raycaster;

let moveForward = false;
let moveBackward = false;
let moveLeft = false;
let moveRight = false;
let canJump = false;

let prevTime = performance.now();
const velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
const direction = new THREE.Vector3();
const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
const color = new THREE.Color();

init();
animate();






//---------- Controls

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.y = 10;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 0, 750 );

    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75 );
    light.position.set( 0.5, 1, 0.75 );
    scene.add( light );

    controls = new PointerLockControls( camera, document.body );

    const blocker = document.getElementById( 'blocker' );
    const instructions = document.getElementById( 'instructions' );

    instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

        controls.lock();

    } );

    controls.addEventListener( 'lock', function () {

        instructions.style.display = 'none';
        blocker.style.display = 'none';

    } );

    controls.addEventListener( 'unlock', function () {

        blocker.style.display = 'block';
        instructions.style.display = '';

    } );

    scene.add( controls.getObject() );

    const onKeyDown = function ( event ) {

        switch ( event.code ) {

            case 'ArrowUp':
            case 'KeyW':
                moveForward = true;
                break;

            case 'ArrowLeft':
            case 'KeyA':
                moveLeft = true;
                break;

            case 'ArrowDown':
            case 'KeyS':
                moveBackward = true;
                break;

            case 'ArrowRight':
            case 'KeyD':
                moveRight = true;
                break;

            case 'Space':
                if ( canJump === true ) velocity.y += 350;
                canJump = false;
                break;

        }

    };

    const onKeyUp = function ( event ) {

        switch ( event.code ) {

            case 'ArrowUp':
            case 'KeyW':
                moveForward = false;
                break;

            case 'ArrowLeft':
            case 'KeyA':
                moveLeft = false;
                break;

            case 'ArrowDown':
            case 'KeyS':
                moveBackward = false;
                break;

            case 'ArrowRight':
            case 'KeyD':
                moveRight = false;
                break;

        }

    };

    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown );
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp );

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ), 0, 10 );

    // floor

    let floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 100, 100 );
    floorGeometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

    // vertex displacement

    let position = floorGeometry.attributes.position;

    for ( let i = 0, l = position.count; i < l; i ++ ) {

        vertex.fromBufferAttribute( position, i );

        vertex.x += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
        vertex.y += Math.random() * 2;
        vertex.z += Math.random() * 20 - 10;

        position.setXYZ( i, vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z );

    }

    floorGeometry = floorGeometry.toNonIndexed(); // ensure each face has unique vertices

    position = floorGeometry.attributes.position;
    const colorsFloor = [];

    for ( let i = 0, l = position.count; i < l; i ++ ) {

        color.setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
        colorsFloor.push( color.r, color.g, color.b );

    }

    floorGeometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colorsFloor, 3 ) );

    const floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: true } );

    const floor = new THREE.Mesh( floorGeometry, floorMaterial );
    scene.add( floor );

    // objects

    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 20 ).toNonIndexed();

    position = boxGeometry.attributes.position;
    const colorsBox = [];

    for ( let i = 0, l = position.count; i < l; i ++ ) {

        color.setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
        colorsBox.push( color.r, color.g, color.b );

    }

    boxGeometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colorsBox, 3 ) );

    for ( let i = 0; i < 500; i ++ ) {

        const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { specular: 0xffffff, flatShading: true, vertexColors: true } );
        boxMaterial.color.setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

        const box = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, boxMaterial );
        box.position.x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ) * 20;
        box.position.y = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 ) * 20 + 10;
        box.position.z = Math.floor( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ) * 20;

        scene.add( box );
        objects.push( box );

    }

    //

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

}





function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}



function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    const time = performance.now();

    if ( controls.isLocked === true ) {

        raycaster.ray.origin.copy( controls.getObject().position );
        raycaster.ray.origin.y -= 10;

        const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

        const onObject = intersections.length > 0;

        const delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;

        velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
        velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

        velocity.y -= 9.8 * 100.0 * delta; // 100.0 = mass

        direction.z = Number( moveForward ) - Number( moveBackward );
        direction.x = Number( moveRight ) - Number( moveLeft );
        direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions

        if ( moveForward || moveBackward ) velocity.z -= direction.z * 400.0 * delta;
        if ( moveLeft || moveRight ) velocity.x -= direction.x * 400.0 * delta;

        if ( onObject === true ) {

            velocity.y = Math.max( 0, velocity.y );
            canJump = true;

        }

        controls.moveRight( - velocity.x * delta );
        controls.moveForward( - velocity.z * delta );

        controls.getObject().position.y += ( velocity.y * delta ); // new behavior

        if ( controls.getObject().position.y < 10 ) {

            velocity.y = 0;
            controls.getObject().position.y = 10;

            canJump = true;

        }

    }

    prevTime = time;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

here's my app.js with a basic expression server setup

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/build', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build')));
app.use('/jsm/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/examples/jsm')));

app.listen(3000, () =>
    console.log('Visit http://127.0.0.1:3000')
);
```

and here ist the console error im experiencing:

```
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'instructions.addEventListener')
    init (client.js:61)
    Modulcode (client.js:33)
    evaluate
    moduleEvaluation
    (anonyme Funktion)
    promiseReactionJob
```

Im probably sitting on a basic mistake but still can't solve it.
Ive been also battling (won the battle tho) to understand how to integrate threejs via es6 module so maybe the mistake is somewhere around there. Im happy to provide further information on my document structure if needed.

Thanks a lot.
David

Comment: Your code is well set out, but you may want to remove extra comments like "I've been struggling to integrate them quite a bit.". "im quite frustrated at this point and very thankful for any help". We're all frustrated when we come here. If you edit your post, you may get more replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this markup:

```
<div class="instructions">
```

And this JS code:

```
const instructions = document.getElementById( 'instructions' );
```

You can't query the DOM element in this way since it has no `id` attribute. You need this:

```
<div id="instructions">
```

> I am using the example from the THREEJS examples page and I've basically copied the exact thing over

Well, the example does properly use the `id` attribute.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/94f043c4e105eb73236529231388402da2b07cba/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html#L49